# How to get rows where a condition in range of columns is met?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('sai','ram','deepika','sahithi','kumar','scott','Don','Lin'), number = c(0,1,2,3,1,0,2,1), number2different = c(0,1,1,1,2,1,1,0), number3differentname = c(0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2))
```

And if wanted to select or create a subset where only the rows from the column called `name` showed where all the other columns had a value of 0--for example, Sai, which only has values next to it that equal 0--which command would work the best?

I tried searching about selecting rows based on columns but the conditions are always for a single column. Is there a way to select rows based on conditions for a range of columns to be met?

Answer (score 0):

You could use tidyverse "filter" with multiple conditions using "&":

```
df %>% filter(number == 0 & number2different == 0 & number3different == 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you know if ther is any way to do this withut dply the %>% doesnt work on my computer, and also i have more than 3 columns so i was looking for a way to do it in 50+ columns

Comment: You could make a new column of the sums of all other columns using tidyverse mutate:
df%>%
     mutate(Total = rowSums(.))
Then filter(Total == 0).
I am not sure how to do it without the pipe, do you have the tidyverse package installed?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Sample Data
df <- data.frame(name = c('sai','ram','deepika','sahithi','kumar','scott','Don','Lin'),
  number = c(0,1,2,3,1,0,2,1),
  number2different = c(0,1,1,1,2,1,1,0),
  number3differentname = c(0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2))

# Subsetting by the 'name' column those rows where all other columns equal zero
df$name[rowSums(df[names(df) != "name"]) == 0]

# Subsetting by row where the specified columns sum to zero
df[rowSums(df[names(df) != "name"]) == 0,]

# Subsetting by row where the specified columns fall within the range (1:2)
df[rowSums(sapply(df[names(df) != "name"], function(x) x >= 1 & x <= 2)) == ncol(df[names(df) != "name"]),]
```

Comment: Hi i tried this, but it creates a vector , what im looking is to have as an output the rows that follow the condition like sai then 0 and 0, and do you know what would be the synthax for do it for a range instead of a single number like those bigger than 0 but smaller than 0 ?

Comment: See my revised answer with two additional options. If those aren't what you're looking for, then I'd recommend revising your original question and including an example of the desired output so we can have a better idea of what you're hoping to end up with.